# TCP C++ client to receive a byte array from a c# server

Tags: c#, c++, tcp, winsock, winsock2

I have a C++ client waiting for an answer from a C# server using winsock2.
The C# server sends the answer as a Byte Array.
The C++ client receives it with negative values.
I tried using an unsigned char array in C++ but winsock doesn't support it in the recv() function.
What am I missing?

C# side:

```
private void Send(byte[] arrayToSend, NetworkStream stream)
{
if (stream.CanWrite) { stream.Write(arrayToSend, 0, arrayToSend.Length); stream.Flush(); }
else { ... }
}
```

C++ Side:

```
TCPConnection::Receive(int timeout, char recv[BUFFER_LENGTH])
{
int iResult = recv(m_socket, recv, BUFFER_LENGTH, 0);
if (iResult <= 0) { ... }
recv[iResult] = '\0';

//FOR DEBUG
std::string s(recv, iResult);
}
```

Comment: When writing communicating programs, you should always **look** what actually transits between them, because if you don't, you can never be sure what programm messed up. Install Wireshark or tcpdump and listen to the communication.

Comment: I saw, the dump from the send is different from the receive end. I'm pretty sure its a small convertion thing in the C++ side that I'm missing

Comment: [mcve] is needed.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - Added the code, sorry - forgot about :)

Comment: What do you mean by `winsock doesn't support it in the recv() function` - isn't the buffer argument for `recv()` declared as a `void*`?

Comment: Okay, well you're sending a byte array on the C# sode, but it appears you're trying to interpret it as a string on the C++ side. You have the data in a buffer, but you're calling the string constructor, which is probably where you're going wring. Before writing code, you should define your protocol  (on paper). Lay out the fields, their data types, and endianness. Then you can go about implementing it in whatever language. Because we don't kow what you're sending, we can't really tell you how to dissect it.

Comment: Concerning C/C++: `char` is either signed or unsigned. Per standard this is implementation defined by compiler. (If a specific signed-ness is required use `signed char` or `unsigned char`.) In your case, I bet `char` is signed. So, everything >= 0x80 appears as negative number.

Comment: *"The C++ client receives it with negative values"* - what does that mean? The return from `recv()` is negative? Or what?

Comment: You need to show the code sending the data (we need to see the data you send) and the code interpreting the data - why do you think it is "negative"?

Comment: When you read elements from `char recv[]`, just convert them to `unsigned char` and they will appear positive. E.g. `int value0 = (unsigned char)recv[0];` (in opposition to `int value0 = recv[0];` where sign bit extension happens so that `value0` stores the same negative value as `recv[0]` does.)

Comment: Btw. in you code sample, the argument `recv` has the same name than the function `recv()` you intend to use. I wonder if this compiles without error. (`int iResult = ::recv(m_socket, recv, BUFFER_LENGTH, 0);` has probably better chances but I recommend simply to rename argument `recv`.)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll try with the unsigned comment, I think it's just that. I'm sorry about the vagueness of the question, it just that simple thing that doesn't work, the structure, layout and surroundings work OK.

Comment: Btw. if provided address for argument `recv` has really only `BUFFER_LENGTH` elements then `recv[iResult] = '\0'` is out of range access if the ful amount of `BUFFER_LENGTH` bytes has been received. (For this, you need storage for at least `BUFFER_LENGTH + 1` elements.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some years of working with C# and Python I forgot about the signed and unsigned char*. That was the problem.. Thanks for helping!